# Gradient direction confusion

Tags: vector-analysis

I've been reading the whole day and now I'm more confused then when I started. Some say that gradient is always perpendicular, and others say it always shows the direction of steepest slope, which should mean tangent? 
Lets take simple functions like:

$f_1(x)=x^2$

$f_2(x, y)=x^2+0.5y^2$

The gradients should be?

$grad f_1(x) = \frac{df}{dx}\hat i=2x\hat i $

$grad f_2(x,y) = \frac{\delta f}{\delta x}\hat i + \frac{\delta f}{\delta y}\hat j 
=2x\hat i+y\hat j $

As I get it, these vectors really point in the direction on the steepest slope, and their magnitudes are proportional to the slope steepness. But they are neither tangent or orthogonal to the curve f(x) and surface f(x,y). For the first function it is a vector on an x axis, and for the second function it a vector on an x-y plane.

But if I write the functions differently:

$x^2-y=0$

$x^2+0.5y^2-z=0$

And then do partial derivatives of the left sides, I get some components:

$ 2x\hat i -\hat j $

$2x\hat i+y\hat j-\hat k$

These vectors seems to be orthogonal to the curve and the surface, but what are they?

Also, what would be the gradient of a plane that is angled 45° to the x-y plane cutting it along x axis? Where would it point to, and what would be it's vector components.

Comment: $\nabla f(x)$ is always perpendicular to the level curve of $f$ through the point $x$.  Also, $\nabla f(x)$ points in the direction of steepest ascent for $f$ at $x$.  These two statements are consistent.  If you're standing at $x$, and you want to increase the value of $f$, should you start walking along a level curve?  No, because then the value of $f$ will not change at all.

Comment: OK, it is perpendicular to the level curve, but it can point various directions from that single point on a level curve, and still be perpendicular to it. Where exactly does it point? Straight up into the sky, into the hill, up the hill (tangentially)?

Comment: Keep in mind that if $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, and $x \in \mathbb R^2$, then $\nabla f(x)$ is an element of $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R^3$.  There are only *two* directions in which $\nabla f(x)$ could point in order to be orthogonal to the level curve of $f$ through $x$.  There are not various directions from that single point, only two.

Comment: So, for a function of two independent variables, which is in fact a 3D surface, gradient lies on a plane parallel to x-y plane? So, it is neither tangent, nor orthogonal to the surface itself. It is just orthogonal to the level curve of the surface at that particular point?

Comment: And then about the last paragraph of my question, for a plane $f(x, y)=x $, it's gradient lies down in an x-y plane, it is always equal to one, and is pointed same as x axis for all the points?

Comment: For example, let's visualize the gradient of the function $f(x,y) = x$ at the point $(2,3)$.  $\nabla f(2,3) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  It has only two components and is an element of $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R^3$.  The level curve of $f$ through the point $(2,3)$ is the vertical line $\{ (x,y) \mid x = 2 \}$.  Notice that this line is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, not $\mathbb R^3$.  The gradient vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is perpendicular to this level curve.

Comment: You meant to say that level curve is horizontal line, but I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say horizontal line? The value of $f$ is not constant along a horizontal line.  The level curves of $f$ in this example are parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Disregarding this function, shouldn't a level curve of f(x,y) always be horizontal? In a plane that's parallel with x-y plane? So in this example, for x=2, we have that f(x,y) is always equal to 2, disregarding the y value. That's how we get a level curve that is actually a straight horizontal line parallel with y-axis? Maybe my math terminology is bad, and we're not talking about the same thing?

Comment: Oh, I see, we were using the term "horizontal" in two different ways.  But, it seems like you are thinking of a level curve of $f$ as being a subset of $\mathbb R^3$, whereas in fact the level curves of $f$ are just subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.  If $f(x,y) = x$, then the level curves of $f$ are lines in $\mathbb R^2$ which are parallel to the $y$-axis.  When I picture these level curves, I'm just picturing the $x-y$ plane, not a 3D picture.

Comment: Here's another example.  When I visualize the level curves of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, I visualize a picture like this:  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultiVrbleFcns_files/image010.gif

Comment: No, this time I'm aware that level curves are confined to a 2D plane, when expressed in mathematical notation, it's just when I talk about them I visualize this: http://www2.gcc.edu/dept/math/faculty/BancroftED/buscalc/chapter4/images/image020.png

Comment: As I see it level curve of  f(x,y)=x should be a straight horizontal line parallel to y axis, and lying in the plane z=2?

Comment: I gave a vote to the question because the post has a good point.  In two dimensions the perpendicularity to the level surface can only be displayed two dimensional but in 3 dimensions it points up to the direction of greatest increase or decrease if negative.  So the question is a very good one.  The problem arises because textbooks insist on jumping back and forth between 2 and 3 dimensions ...they should draw the gradient in 3 D not on a flat level curve to show what direction it points in 3D because you can't really do it in 2 D